# Null Pointer Exception is thrown

Tags: struts2

In my Struts Application, there is a Register form in a Jsp. The values enterd in it are then stored to mysql Db by means of an action class.

The action class (Register.java) for inserting values to mysql Db is:

```
 package com.login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Register extends ActionSupport {



String regname;
String regpass;
String regmail;

public String getRegname() {
    return regname;
}

public void setRegname(String regname) {
    this.regname = regname;
}

public String getRegpass() {
    return regpass;
}

public void setRegpass(String regpass) {
    this.regpass = regpass;
}

public String getRegmail() {
    return regmail;
}

public void setRegmail(String regmail) {
    this.regmail = regmail;
}


Connection con;
 Statement st;
 ResultSet rs;

public void connect(){

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vijay","root", "pwd");

        //*.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/shoppingmall","root", "vijay");      
        st=con.createStatement();*

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void queree(){
    try {
        //*st.executeUpdate("insert into prodet (name,password,email) values('"+this.getRegname()+"','"+this.getRegpass()+"','"+this.getRegmail()+"');");*

        st.executeUpdate("insert into prodet (name,caty) values('"+this.getRegname()+"','"+this.getRegpass()+"');");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    this.connect();
    this.queree();

    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

**The Jsp:**

```
<s:form action="/loginns/register" cssStyle="float:right; background-color:lightgreen" method="POST">
<h5 align="center">Register here</h5>   <br>
<s:textfield name="regname" label="UserName"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="regpass" label="Password"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="regmail" label="email"></s:textfield>
<s:submit align="center" value="Register"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

**Struts.xml:**

```
<package name="Login" namespace="/loginns" extends="struts-default">
<action name="register" class="com.login.Register">
        <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Registered.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Everything works fine. On clicking the Register button, it succesfully displays the resultant page. No Exceptions are thrown.
But on Db the values are not updated. Tried in 2 Dbs but the same result. *(The code in italics are for the Db in Mysql workbench 6.0)* What do i miss?

Comment: On changing the method to st.executeUpdate(), it throws NullPointer Exception in the 'queree' method.

Comment: Italics doesn't work on code blocks. Discover which field is null and why. Put printlog before calling your methods and print the variables values. Also use variable names, not `this.getter`... ?

Comment: Those String values are returned null.

Comment: Add `private` to your variables, and look what is sent with Firebug NET panel

Comment: @VijayaRagavan Did you try to save it somewhere in memory before marshaling it to the db?

Answer (score 0):

You must call executeUpdate for updates and inserts, executeQuery only for selects.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: Thank you pal. Now it throws a Null Pointer Exception. Related to Struts.